# List of modules working with ironpython

Tags: python, ironpython

Is there a place that lists standard library and 3rd party modules that work with IronPython? If not, please let me know here.

Here are some I have tried:

- cherrypy - works with [fepy](http://fepy.sourceforge.net/doc/fepy-options.html) - [example](http://groups.google.com/group/cherrypy-users/browse_thread/thread/af7959f06420921e)
- comtypes: has no hope until ctypes is functional which seems far off still.
- dulwich: builds after removing optional extensions from setup.py file.  Imports after adding in jdhardy's zlib and subprocess modules.  Seems to pass its own tests.
- numpy, parts of scipy[: pytools](http://pytools.codeplex.com/)
- [rpyc](http://rpyc.sourceforge.net/) works out of the box.  Awesome library so you can remotely use cpython ojects from ironpython and vice versa

Comment: Standard library: should all be working, it's part of Python. Other modules should work so long as they're entirely written in Python, but many authors won't test on IronPython (not criticising, I never have). C extensions won't work, although there is a project aiming for that: http://www.resolversystems.com/products/ironclad/

Comment: There are a couple bugs in IronPython that pure Python code can still run into, but most modules should work fine. For example, Jinja2  [references the unicode function](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/29505) which causes problems when using non-ASCII characters

Answer (score 1):

The official IronPython website has [a page that lists the compatibility status of third-party libraries](http://www.ironpython.info/index.php/Third-Party_Library_Compatibility).

*However*, currently only two libraries are listed.  If you're a third-party library developer and you know how well your library works with IronPython, it would be great to add it there.

Answer (score 0):

pywin32 and PyODBC go away, replaced by the FCL (optionally using one of the ODBC .NET data providers if you're married to ODBC). CherryPy is pure Python and so should mostly work; I'm sure the developers would be interested in hearing about any problems. For NumPy there's [Ironclad](http://www.resolversystems.com/documentation/index.php/Ironclad).

Answer (score 0):

numpy and parts of scipy now work with ironpython: http://pytools.codeplex.com/